# Parameterized type keys for Map

Tags: java, generics, type-safety, raw-types

I am learning Java and am currently reading Joshua Bloch's Effective Java.

In Item 29, he discusses parameterized type keys for Map to create a type-safe heterogeneous map. Here is the code:

```
class Favorites {
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

    public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance) {
        if (type == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Type is null");
        favorites.put(type, instance);
    }

    public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> type) {
        return type.cast(favorites.get(type));
    }
}
```

He goes on to say that

> A malicious client could easily corrupt the type safety of a Favorites
>   instance, simply by using a Class object in its raw form. But the
>   resulting client code would generate an unchecked warning when it was
>   compiled.

I know that `Class<T>` would be erased to Class. But I am not sure how a malicious client can break the type safety at compile time. I tried various ways, but I always got a compiler error, as I expected.

Can someone please tell me what exactly Joshua Bloch meant in the line quoted above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A raw type is one that doesn't have generic information. Here's how you can defeat the type safety of the method:

```
Favorites favorites = new Favorites();
favorites.putFavorite((Class)Integer.class, "foo"); // no compile error
```

whereas this won't compile:

```
favorites.putFavorite(Integer.class, "foo"); // compile error
```

Because the type of the parameter is `Class` (and not `Class<T>`), the generic method parameter `T` can not be determined and type inference is switched off for that call. It's as if the code making the call is pre-generics, with which java is backwardly compatible (by ignoring generics).

Here's how you can guard against that problem:

```
public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance) {
    if (type == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Type is null");
    if (!type.isInstance(instance)) // add check for instance type
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class/instance mismatch");
    favorites.put(type, instance);
}
```

or more brutally (as you can't be as informative with the error message), simply attempt the cast:

```
public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance) {
    if (type == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Type is null");
    favorites.put(type, type.cast(instance)); // will throw ClassCastException
}
```

but that will only pick up a problem at *runtime* when the malicious code attempts to do damage, but it's still better than picking up the problem at *usage* time when some other client tries to use the dodgy instance.

Comment: Or, in a less weird way: `Class integerClass = Integer.class; favorites.putFavorite(integerClass, "foo");`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: The point here is that the `<T>` in the signature helps avoid problems, but to enforce clean data, you need to prevent corruption: the putFavorite implementation should have done: `favorites.put(type, type.cast(instance))`